# Do online billpay/banking force NSFs (Not Sufficient Funds) when they can?

Tags: fees, online-banking, online-payment, overdraft, nsf

When online banking and payment systems first came out, I remember they used to have a lot of issues with giving indicators (visual/email payment confirmation) that a payment was 'locked in', but then due to delays/misreading etc. would end up forcing an insufficient funds fee (NSF) on the client, which we would then have to correct.

There was *idle* speculation that some of this may have been due to intentional software design, and I'm wondering if anyone has researched or knows anything about whether that is still a thing (NSF by design)?

Comment: If there was enough money in your account, and you kept track of it, then you wouldn't have anything to worry about.

Comment: Having said that, payments get registered **very** quickly to my Chase checking account, from DC, bill payment services, etc.

Comment: Just a side note...is this site so unfriendly to new people? Like I always see new contributors getting downvote on a normal legitimate question.

Comment: @gamma: It's not a normal legitimate question.  It's a rant.  You can tell, because it doesn't ask a question and the information it seeks is not constructive/actionable.  It could be made into a useful question, however, by asking "What can I do to avoid NSF fees? (even ones that are carefully crafted to trap users)"

Comment: I'm sure it's happened once or twice. That doesn't mean it's common. It certainly doesn't mean it isn't avoidable, if you just stay aware of your balance and/or maintain some buffer funds in the account. I think you're worrying about something out of your control while ignoring the part that is completely under your control.

Answer (score 1):

[In 2014, the Washington Post reported that some US banks reordered transactions to maximize overdraft fees](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/07/17/wells-fargo-to-make-changes-to-protect-customers-from-overdraft-fees/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.a5a511362ec2). This was perfectly legal, though underhanded. I do not know what the current state of affairs is. This is the type of issue the [Consumer Financial Protection Bureau](https://www.consumerfinance.gov) was created to address.